# Update several rows from a select using values from the select query

Tags: mysql

I try something like this:

```
UPDATE features f2
SET f2.description = REPLACE(f2.description,f.name,CONCAT("<span 
class='condition'>",f.name,"<input type='hidden' class='id' value='",f.id,"' /></span>"))
FROM features f2 
RIGHT JOIN features f 
ON (LOCATE(concat(" ",f.name),f2.description)>0) 
WHERE f.id_ft=2 AND f2.id_ft=12
```

But it is not working.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM features f2 RIGHT JOIN features f ON (LOCATE(concat(" ",f.name),f2.desc' at line 3

The idea is replacing some text within a field from *features* table with another field text from the same table (but different row). The select That works for me is the following:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, f2.name, f2.id FROM `features` f2 RIGHT JOIN features f ON (LOCATE(concat(' ',f.name),f2.description)>0) WHERE f.id_ft=2 AND f2.id_ft=12 order by f.name, f2.name
```

Any idea?

Comment: Note that nobody ever actually uses RIGHT JOIN. Also, in this instance, this is actually an inner join.

Comment: I changed the RIGHT, now is INNER and the same error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM features f2
INNER JOIN features f
ON (LOCATE(concat(" ",f.name),f2.desc' at line 3

Comment: Now move the SET line to just above the WHERE line

Comment: ...and lose the FROM line